# Vue / Vitest : issues in snapshots with dynamic import assets URL

Tags: vue.js, url, vite, snapshot, vitest

I am migrating my project from Vue-CLI & Jest to Vite & Vitest. Everything worked fine until I tried to make my tests pass through Jenkins. I discovered that some snapshots does not match because of some assets paths.

- Expected : `src="file:///C:/src/..."`  (which is weird because this path does not exist)
- Received : `src="file:///src/..."`

These assets are imported in my `.vue` files using `return new URL("/src/...", import.meta.url).href`.

Of course everything works perfectly locally.

Do you have any idea why, and how I can fix it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: I found why. I was running my local tests on Windows, but the Jenkins ones on Linux. I solved it by using `process.env.VITEST` env variable:

```
export function setDynamicUrl(media: string) {
    return process.env.VITEST
        ? media
        : new URL(`/src/assets/${media}`, import.meta.url).href;
}
```